# How do I set the HTML options for collection_select in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I can't seem to find the syntax to add a class to a select tag generated by Rails [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select). Some help?

Comment: Can you give some example what you want to do? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sure... I'm using rails' <%= f.collection_select ... %> to generate:
<select ...>
...
</select>
I just want it to be:
<select class="foo" ...>
...
</select>

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Many Rails helpers take multiple hash arguments.  The first is usually the options to control the helper itself, and the second is the html_options where you specifiy custom ids, classes etc.

The method definition looks like this:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

You'll notice the multiple '= {}' in the params list.  To use this, the first set of options that you would specify must actually be enclosed in braces:

```
collection_select(:user, :title, UserTitle.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=>true}, {:class=>'my-custom-class'})
```

If you don't have any options to specify besides the html class, then just put an empty hash placeholder:

```
collection_select(:user, :title, UserTitle.all, :id, :name, {}, {:class=>'my-custom-class'})
```

Additional API documentation is available at:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: Here's an extension of this answer showing how to modify .css style and use jQuery onchange events `<%= collection_select(:question , :text, Question.all , :id, :text, {:prompt => 'Select Question...'}, {:class=>'input', :name=>'normalSelect', :id=>'normalSelect', :style=>'width:50%', :onchange=>"$('#accordion').accordion('activate',2);$('#blind').show('blind', 500)"}) %>`

Answer (score 11):

```
= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {class: "store-select"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just in case, I was struggling with the same problem, I share my result, I was trying just putting `{},{}`, so I had to be more explicit putting like this:  `options = {}, html_options = {}`, because it did not work for me.

```
<div class="field">
   <%= form.label :country_id %>
   <%= form.collection_select :country_id, @countries,:id, :name, options = {:prompt => 'Select a Country...'},
        html_options = {class: "dropdown"}%>
 </div>
```

Regards!