# add class to collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, select

I've looked at [How do I set the HTML options for collection_select in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947578/rails-collection-select-html-options) and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't get this to work.

My select currently looks like:

```
  <%= f.collection_select :broadcast_id, broadcasts, :id, :to_s,
    :include_blank => 'Broadcast on...' %>
```

and I've tried including **:class => 'prevent_collapse'**, which does nothing, as well as **{:class => 'prevent_collapse'}**, which gives me an error.

If anyone can point out how to do this, I'll be super grateful!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
=>
f.collection_select :broadcast_id, broadcasts, :id, :to_s,
{:include_blank => 'Broadcast on...'}, {:class => 'prevent_collapse'}
```

**And what error do you have?**

And does broadcast item has got `:to_s` method? It will return class name, as I think.

Comment: thank you - that's solved it!  I was forgetting to put the :include_blank in {}

Comment: you can leave like that: "f.collection_select :broadcast_id, broadcasts, :id, :to_s,
{}, {:class => 'prevent_collapse'}" There is no need to add "include_blank" if you do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

Is that field `:include_blank => {}`, compulsory ? I tried with `:include_blank => false` and it worked. I wonder if we can avoid it ?

Comment: Yes you can skip it. Just replace `{:include_blank => 'Broadcast on...'}` with `{}`.