# Increasing font size in rails collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

How do I increase the font size in collection_select dropdown box for a rails app?

I imagine this could be up with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `collection_select` method allows you to [specify an html options, such as an html class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947578/rails-collection-select-html-options/1947675#1947675), e.g.:

```
collection_select(:user, :title, UserTitle.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=>true}, {:class=>'my-custom-class'})
```

Then, you can style it with CSS:

```
.my-custom-class { font-size: 110%; }
```