# Selecting Records Using collection_select and Using CSS for Formatting

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.0

I have the following collection_select logic in my Rails 3.2.3 form to select states and order them by name.

```
<%= collection_select(:user, :state_id, State.order('name'), :id, :name) %>
```

I have a Country model where the ID is in the State model.  My User model has country_id and state_id.  User belongs to Country and State.  Country has many users and has many States.  States belong to Country.

I would like to only select States for a particular Country.  I want to match the country_id from the User model to the country_id from the State model.  I thought about using **State.where('something;).order('name')**.  However I do not know how I would code the SQL for this.  I am using a PostgreSQL database.  The examples I have found were for other databases.

The second question relates to how the list looks.  I would like to change the background color along with the font color to match the input fields on my website.  I tried the following code but could not get it working.

```
<%= collection_select(:user, :state_id, State.order('name'), :id, :name, {:class=>'collection-select-class'})  %>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.collection-select-class {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: @yellow;
}
```

I also tried using the option tag but it did not change anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS does not currently support that feature.

Look here:

[HTML <select> selected option background-color CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402146/html-select-selected-option-background-color-css-style)

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS related part of this question I'm referencing to answer on the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1947675

In short, you need to add  empty hash {} in order for it to work. So it will be like:

```
<%= collection_select(:user, :state_id, State.order('name'), :id, :name, {}, {:class=>'collection-select-class'})  %>
```

Hope this helps!