# html class in rails collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How to add the html class name to select box in rails

I have tried following methods but getting syntax error

```
<%= f.collection_select :product, @product, :id, :name, selected: @post.product.id, html_options={class: 'tst'} %>

<%= f.collection_select :product, @product, :id, :name, selected: @post.product.id,{class: 'tst'} %>


<%= f.collection_select :product, @product, :id, :name, selected: @post.product.id, html_options: {class: 'tst'} %>
```

Tried all the above three ways but I am unable to fix it how can i add a html class in it.

Comment: Have you checked out the syntax on this previous post? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947578/how-do-i-set-the-html-options-for-collection-select-in-rails

Comment: @emk411 Yes checked already but that doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

i've made something similar work with :class => classname