# Rails: How to add custom data-attributes in collection_select

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am working on a solution to add custom data-attributes to option-tags with the `collection_select` form helper in Rails.

I studied some posts at stackoverflow and did a lot of trial and error after consulting some API documentation. I am nearly there but sadly my solution only adds attributes to the `select`-tag not to the `option`-tags.

This way I am populating the html-options-hash (6th position):

```
<%= f.collection_select(:parallax_id, @parallax.all, :id, :title, {}, { :"data-icon" => @parallax.map{ |p| "#{p.image}"}} ) %>
```

This results in a select tag like:

```
<select data-icon="/uploads/image/image/4/169_strecken-ausgang.jpg" name="game[parallax_id]" id="game_parallax_id">...</select>
```

But I want the option to get the `data-icon` attribute. When I switch positions and add my data-icon to the options-hash (5th position) nothing is output.

Comment: can you give an example of how you want the options to come out in html?

Comment: I want this `data-icon` on the option-tag level, like so: `<option data-icon="/uploads/image/image/4/169_strecken-ausgang.jpg" ...`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
= f.select :parallax_id, options_for_select(@parallax.map {|p| [p.title, p.id, {'data-icon' => p.image }]})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder why it works with the `select` helper but not with the `collection_select` helper. I tried a command similar to yours with `collection_select` before asking the question but it did not provide me with this results. So now I just have to change my app's forms but that's okay. I'm glad that it works like this. It's more convenient as to output the options by hand with a `.each` loop. Thank you. :)

Comment: it works because it's a [documented](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) feature: `You can optionally provide HTML attributes as the last element of the array.`. but i didn't know about it either. +1 hoang.

Comment: this helped me a lot, when trying to figure out how to disable only specific options. I didn't know about the 3rd parameter in the list (name, id, attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI I was looking at this matter, found the more fitting solution here: [How do I set the HTML options for collection_select in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947578/how-do-i-set-the-html-options-for-collection-select-in-rails).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain your answer and do not just past a link (they can get obsolete). [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The post you have linked to answers a different question. The result the questioner is looking for is similar to `<option class="green">asdf</option>`.  The other post generates `<select class="green">....options..</select>`.   (The OP here wants `data-icon` values, but  using  `class` is easier to see in an example.)