# How to change background color of collection_select items in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, collection-select

How can I style the visual drop-down of a collection select in Rails? I want to change the background color of individual items in the drop-down, with the color derived from an attribute in the Affiliation object. Here is the current collection_select:

```
<%= collection_select(:application, :affiliation_id, Affiliation.all.order(:priority).all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true)  %>
```

The Affiliation objects have an attribute called "priority" and I want to assign a color to be displayed based on each Affiliation's priority.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247055/rails-how-to-add-custom-data-attributes-in-collection-select) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052889/ruby-on-rails-f-select-options-with-custom-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

add

```
class: 'color_<%= affiliation.color %>'
```

in collection_select and create same style classe

```
.color_1 { background-color:#colorvalue; }  # for affiliation.color == 1
```

in css file

Answer (score 0):

In you .css file add extra class for collection_select

`.collection_select_background
  {
   background: #color_name;
  }`

And you can use class called `.collection_select_background` i.e

`<%= collection_select(:application, :affiliation_id, Affiliation.all.order(:priority).all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true), **class: collection_select_background**  %>`

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: More for reference http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select