# Add class to bootstrap_form_for collection_select in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I use bootstrap_form_for to create forms and have a collection select, where I want to add a custom class. I tried this, but this does not work:

```
<%= f.collection_select :location, Location.all, :id, :name, label: 'Location', :include_blank => ("Select..."), hide_label: true, :class => 'location' %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `<%= f.collection_select :location, Location.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "location"}` (possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947578/how-do-i-set-the-html-options-for-collection-select-in-rails)

Comment: Hey Kevin, make this an actual answer so I can give you an additional upvote.  And thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Many Rails helpers take multiple hash arguments.

And the definition of this collection_select method looks like this:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So your select field will be:

```
<%= f.collection_select :location, Location.all, :id, :name,
    {label: 'Location', :include_blank => ("Select..."), hide_label: true}, {class: "location"} %>
```