# Add class to select field in Rails 5 with bootstrap_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and bootstrap_form_for to build a form.

I know there are some similar questions in SO but none of the helped me solve my issue...

I am trying to add a custom class to a select field. But I have is this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => ("Insere um endereço ou escolha um local da lista..."), hide_label: true, :class => 'location' %>
```

But the class is not applied. What can I do diferente?

Comment: Try `<%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: "location"} %>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617681/add-class-to-bootstrap-form-for-collection-select-in-rails-5). The subject of the two are different, but then you end up talking about `collection_select` and not `select` in both...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.collection_select(:location_id, Location.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => ("Insere um endereço ou escolha um local da lista..."), hide_label: true}, class: "class-name") %>
```

Comment: Invalid syntax, you need to close the normal brace after the last options. Always useful to make those options hashes at the end explicit though!

Comment: @almo updated in the answer - threw together the answer too fast :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an empty hash for the `options` part of the method parameters. It is not very intuitive I'm afraid but if you look at the [method signature](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) you can see why it's needed.

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) 


<%= f.collection_select :location_id, 
  Location.all, 
  :id, 
  :name, 
  :include_blank => ("Insere um endereço ou escolha um local da lista..."), 
  hide_label: true, 
  {},
 :class => 'location' %>
```